# Virtual machine and memory access issue

Tags: c++, qt, memory, virtual-machine

I'am trying to watch a directory and notify for file changing(creation), I'am using a virtual machine (VirtualBox) on windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 as the guest,  when a file was added to my watched folder I test the existence of this file to get its size and manipulate it later, the problem is: sometimes it return 0 as size although the file exists and have a non zero size, here is my code:

```
void Watcher::OnFileChanged (char* FileBaseName)
{

    QDir watchDir(RootToWatch);
    QString fileN="";
    fileN=QString::fromLocal8Bit(FileBaseName);
    QFileInfo file(RootToWatch+"/"+fileN);
    qDebug()<<"Watcher::OnFileChanged "<<fileN;

    try
       {
       if(file.exists())
       {
           qDebug()<<"FileWatcher::OnFileChanged "<<fileN<<"exists";
           qDebug()<<"OnFileChanged:fileName "<<file.fileName()
                   <<"\nOnFileChanged File().size"<<QFile(fileN).size()
                   <<"\nOnFileChanged QFileInfo Size:"<<file.size();
 ....
       }
       }
}
```

should I wait for laps of time to get the real size (if yes how match and how test if the file is ready to be read) or do I missed some thing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does sound like a typical case of "watcher goes off before the file is finally written" - which would be perfectly expected behaviour really, as all you can say is "tell me if this file has changed" - getting size zero is definitely a change - whether it previously existed or is just coming into existance, it's a change from the previous state.

My approach in this case would be to set the watch again, and see if the file has "grown" next time around.

Comment: thank you for your time, so all I need is to watch until the size grow   and then proceed my work on the file, I will try and see, thank you